# where does render :partial html end up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views, renderpartial

I have a view with an ajax form:

```
<%= form_tag( {:action => 'some_action'}, {:remote => true}) do %>
...
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Now, in the target action, I want to display a partial

```
def some_action
  # some logic
  render :partial => "some_partial"
end
```

The partial is just html. `_some_partial.html.erb` could be

```
<br>Hi, this is the partial</br>
```

When I submit the form, I see the html response packet is received in the browser (with firebug's net logs), but the html doesn't show up anywhere. Where should the html be? How to render a partial html view from an action?

Answer (score 1):

you are rendering a partial but not specifying where to render it.

**in rails 2** you could do it with:

```
def some_action
  # some logic
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html 'some_div_id', :partial => 'some_partial'
  end
end
```

but in rails 3, above code is no longer valid.
see [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)

create a file named **some_action.js.erb** and write the code in it:

```
// update div with id some_div_id
$("#some_div_id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'some_partial') %>");
```

**in controller**

```
def some_action
  # some logic
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, I know the problem is that I am not specifying where to render it. Is there any way to use render :partial inside an action to render an html view though? Perhaps with some way to determine where the html should go?

Comment: you can specify where to render the html and other jquery stuff in some_action.js.erb, here some_action is your action name.

Comment: I understand that this is a workaround. My question is if there is any way to render a .html partial from an action.

Comment: you can render a partial from controller but you can not update html elements from controller.

Comment: I guess you can actually send a .html.erb response, but you still need some js to actually put it in it's place. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to send and display html. From [theReq](http://tech.thereq.com/post/17243732577/rails-3-using-link-to-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs?34158170), just add `:remote => true, "data-type" => "html"` to the form and then in the javascript of the page, capture the returned html on ajaxSuccess to display it:

```
$('form#whatever').on('ajaxSuccess', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
    $('div#target').html(data);
  }
)
```